# Front info panel in VW Golf Estate Diesel 1,9 TDi 2008

Tags: fuel-system, vw, golf

I bought a couple of days ago VW Gold estate diesel 1.9 TDI Bluemotion from 2008. Unfortunately, the previous owner did not provide a manual for it and this is insanely expensive to order the duplicate.

I was just wondering if someone could at least help me with information in front panel (dashboard)--the one between speed and revolution meters. I can see it is split into 3 section s: top, middle and bottom. The top and bottom sections show always the same info such as clock or overall miles and a trip etc. The middle section can have seven different screens. Please I would be grateful if someone would explain what they represent. Some of them were easier to guess:

- Screen 1: "ø 55.5 mpg"
  I believe it shows average miles per gallon. There's a little digit 2 in the right upper corner and I don't know what it is
- Screen 2: "104 mpg"
  An instant miles per gallon. Without digit 2 in the corner
- Screen 3: 31 h 38 min - with 2 in the corner
  ?
- Screen 4: "Speed warning --- mph"
  Does not seem to change
- Screen 5: "ø 23 mph"
  I guess this is average speed.
- Screen 6: "726 miles" - 
  ?
- Screen 7: " 260 miles" -
  ?

Another question is if I can reset all the stats.

I will be grateful for the answer. Cheers!

Comment: I found the [Owner's manual online in PDF format](http://www.volkswagen.co.uk/assets/common/pdf/brochures/old-brochure/Golf/Golf-July-2008.pdf) ... all it says about the function of the display is how great it is. While I hate to direct you this way from our lovely site, I think your best bet is to go to a VW Users Forum and ask the question there. When you find out the answers to your questions, come back here and answer it for yourself :D

Answer (score 1):

I have made a thread on one of the [VW forums](http://www.volkswagenforum.co.uk/f22/readings-front-driver-vw-golf-estate-1-9-tdi-diesel-bluemotion-17471.html). Thanks to people there I have been given a [link](http://www.myturbodiesel.com/wiki/multifunction-display-mfi-or-mfd-faq-and-menu-settings-mk5-mk6/) with some explanations. Hope this will also help the others :)

Answer (score 0):

The readings are off of your trip computer. The little numbers in the corner are for differant trips - say business or pleasure, differant drivers etc. You do not need a workshop manual. The vehicle should have a 'drivers handbook' to give you all the operational details you need. If you do not have one they are available from your VW maindealer at modest cost.

Comment: Thanks Allan. The handbook is for £90. It's very expensive.

Comment: Could it be possible to have explanation on those stats I did not manage to guess? I would be grateful. Cheers!

Comment: If you go onto the 'erWin-portal' you can look at all the information on VAG, for a very modest hourly rate which is includes printing rights. Also Ross-Tech have a Wiki feature which I am sure you will find very useful and is free of charge.

Comment: I've found the [owner's manual online in pdf format](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.volkswagen.co.uk%2Fassets%2Fcommon%2Fpdf%2Fbrochures%2Fold-brochure%2FGolf%2FGolf-July-2008.pdf&ei=sv3cU9u0MMGWyAS_5IKoAw&usg=AFQjCNHLfd8k-sf661c3hdOjbtA733P-lg&sig2=NYRiMWjKj0NAhBijhB8tdQ&bvm=bv.72197243,d.aWw) ... it just says how great the display is and not much on how it works or its functions.

Comment: The erWin portal is where you go when you need any VW/Audi information. It is VAG's own site for garages world wide.